# View with a lot of UIButtons are slowing switch animation between views

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have UIViewController with many UIButtons (>30). But my animation between previous and next views is slow and with spurts. If I commented all of buttons - animation is going to work correctly. How can I fix this problem? My project use ARC mode (in this I think couldn't be memory leaks)

Comment: No, leaks wouldn't slow this down.  It's UINavigationController trying to push a most likely massive view controller onto the stack.

Comment: @CodaFi what do you mean "likely massive view controller"? can you give me some code as answer?

Comment: Your massive view with all the buttons is already in memory, so what's on the second view?  Or is it blank.

Comment: @CodaFi actually I didn't know how to do this. In next view I have a same situation view with I lot of uibuttons.

Comment: there's your problem.  That amount of buttons must have a huge effect on memory and speed.  Why not load those suckers after the view is pushed?

Comment: @CodaFi you mean implement all my buttons in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12639/discussion-between-romanhouse-and-codafi)